# Can't assign admin rights in my repository

Tags: github

I have a public github account. I need to assign admin rights to someone in one of my repositories. But when I go to settings > Collaborators >. There is no dropdown to assign rights next to the charactor's name. Can someone tell me how to fix it? Thanks.[This is the screenshot of my github path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTnyC.png)

I have tried with some google docs and youtube videos. But couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Repository ownership can't be shared with anyone in Personal Account. You can only invite collaborators which have limited rights. Ref [About permissions levels for a personal account repository](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-personal-account-on-github/managing-personal-account-settings/permission-levels-for-a-personal-account-repository#about-permissions-levels-for-a-personal-account-repository)